# How to interact layers with a nested loop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, loop, error-000732

I've dealing with the code below with such a long time. I have to show in a raster image the result of calculating the cost of the electricity for a solar plant. The thing is that I have to interact a layer "DNI" (direct normal irradiation) with the formula, and the value of the formula changes with a factor for each year (costReductionFactorPlant) during the 30  years of the life plant. The factors are shown below.

When I run the code, I receive the following error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 56, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4049, in Times
    in_raster_or_constant2)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4046, in wrapper
    return _wrapLocalFunctionRaster(u"Times_sa", ["Times", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset D:_ArcGIS\Python\LCOE_test does not exist or is not supported
>>>
```

I'm afraid that there is something wrong when calling the layer "DNI". But no clue. Maybe there is also an error with the loop... I've tryed to look at it also, for me looks good, but I'm not an expert.

I'm running ArcGis 10.1.

CODE:

```
import arcpy, os, sys
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set Workspace
env.workspace = "D:\02_ArcGIS\Python\LCOE_test"

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Variables definition
capacity = 100000
actualOutput = .94 * capacity
storageHours = 16
loadFactor = (.57 * storageHours + 7.1)/24
costReductionFactorPlant = [0.4790, 0.4533, 0.4297, 0.4080, 0.3880, 0.3696, 0.3526, 0.3368, 0.3222, 0.3087, 0.2961, 0.2844, 0.2735, 0.2633, 0.2538, 0.2449, 0.2366, 0.2288, 0.2215, 0.2146, 0.2081, 0.2021, 0.1964, 0.1910, 0.1859, 0.1811, 0.1765, 0.1723, 0.1682, 0.1643, 0.1607]
efficiency = [0.1822, 0.1827, 0.1831, 0.1834, 0.1837, 0.1840, 0.1841, 0.1843, 0.1844, 0.1845, 0.1846, 0.1847, 0.1847, 0.1848, 0.1848, 0.1849, 0.1849, 0.1849, 0.1849, 0.1849, 0.1849, 0.1850, 0.1850, 0.1850, 0.1850, 0.1850, 0.1850, 0.1850, 0.1850, 0.1850, 0.1850]
years = 30
i = .1
ir = .01
lcoePlantTotal = 0
productionPlant = loadFactor * actualOutput * 8760
DNI =  "D:\02_ArcGIS\Python\LCOE_test" #layer#

Count=len(costReductionFactorPlant)+ 1
counter=1

while counter < Count:
    for i in range(counter,(counter+1)):

            # Set the cell size environment using a keyword.
            arcpy.env.cellSize = "MAXOF"

            # Set the extent environment using a keyword
            arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"

            #intermediate formula plant

            # size = (capacity * 8760 * loadFactor)/(DNI * efficiency[counter-1])

            size1 = (capacity * 8760 * loadFactor)
            timesConstant = efficiency[counter-1]
            size2 = Times(3, timesConstant)
            print size2
            size = Divide(size1, size2)

            # Calculate power block & storage              
            powerBlock = capacity * 1484.9918 * costReductionFactorPlant[counter-1]
            storage = storageHours * capacity * 39.45759 * costReductionFactorPlant[counter-1]

            # Calculate mirrowField 
            # mirrorField = size * 155.6975 * costReductionFactorPlant[cont-1]
            timesConstant2 = costReductionFactorPlant[counter-1]
            inconstant = Times(155.6975, timesConstant2)
            mirrorField = Times(size, inconstant)

            # calculate PowerTower
            powerTower = ((capacity * 121.03883) + (capacity * 128.50378)) * costReductionFactorPlant[counter-1]

            # Calculate investmentPlant
            investmentPlant = powerBlock + storage + mirrorField + powerTower

            # Calculate omPlant
            omPlant = Times(investmentPlant, 0.048)

            #formula: lcoePlant = ((investmentPlant * (((i * (1 + i)^counter)/((1 + i)^counter-1))+ ir))+omPlant)/productionPlant*100
            # Formula Part 1 = (investmentPlant * (((i * (1 + i)^counter) Power symbol = **
            InConstant3= i * ((1 + i)**counter)
            FormulaPart1 = Times(investmentPlant, InConstant3)

            # Formula Part 2 = ((1 + i)^counter-1))+ ir))+omPlant)/productionPlant*100
            FormulaPart2 =(((1 + i)**(counter-1)+ ir)+omPlant)/productionPlant*100

            # Formula
            lcoePlant = Divide(FormulaPart1, FormulaPart2)

            lcoePlantTotal = lcoePlantTotal + lcoePlant

            lcoePlantTotal.save = "D:\\02_ArcGIS\\Python" + str(lcoePlantTotal) + ".img"

print "lcoePlanttotal calculated"
```

Comment: Does the raster DNI indeed exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Jens mentions about correcting the path syntax, another problem is the workspace\input layer distinction. In the code you posted, env.workspace and DNI are identical, and the stack trace indicates that DNI is incorrectly set.

```
env.workspace = "D:\02_ArcGIS\Python\LCOE_test"

DNI =  "D:\02_ArcGIS\Python\LCOE_test"
```

I'm assuming LCOE_test is a folder, which will work fine as the workspace. However, for DNI you need to specify further. Depending on DNI's format, it will look something like

```
DNI = "D:\\02_ArcGIS\\Python\\LCOE_test\\DNI"
```

I also don't see DNI being called within the while loop (except for a commented line). I'm guessing this is a result of your debugging efforts, though.

Comment: I have runned it three times: One with the slash \, \\, /. And the path of the layer "DNI" id properly defined. Nevertheless I still geting this error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 47, in <module>

Comment: File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4049, in Times
    in_raster_or_constant2)

Comment: File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4046, in wrapper
    return _wrapLocalFunctionRaster(u"Times_sa", ["Times", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])

Comment: RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset D:/02_ArcGIS/Python/LCOE_test/DNI does not exist or is not supported
>>>

Comment: But the layer "DNI" still does not exist! THAAAANKS!!! :)

Comment: Hi guys!! I've changed how I called the layer and how I saved the final result into this:                       DNI = os.path.join(D:/02_ArcGIS/Python/LCOE_test/DNI,DNI + .img)......................lcoePlantTotal.save = os.path.join(D:/02_ArcGIS/Python, holahola + .img) .......................And the Error000732 has disappeard!! But still one error in line 6. And that is: env.workspace = (D:/02_ArcGIS/Python/LCOE_test). What is wrong with that? Thought it was in the right way! Thks!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please don't try to put code/error messages in the comments section. Edit your question instead, referencing a particular answer if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The paths with a single backslash are no valid paths. Use:

- one forward slash:

> "c:/test/test.shp"

- Two backslash:

> "c:\\test\\test.shp"

- letter r before a string containing a backslash:

> r"c:\test\test.shp"

Comment: Thanks guys. I've modified "\\" and defined the total route for the layer "DNI".
Yes, this layer exists, is a .img ratster contained in the folder LCOE_test.

The problem I've seen lies in this layer. I've writen a print "Ok" and it gives and error before the print "Ok1". Excatly the line where the layer is called.
No idea what happens. If the raster .img exists and the folder exists and this is teh exact path. What else can be wrong?

Comment: The modifications in the code: 
    env.workspace = "D:\\02_ArcGIS\\Python\\LCOE_test"
    DNI =  "D:\\02_ArcGIS\\Python\\LCOE_test\\DNI" #layer#
    size2 = Times(DNI, timesConstant)
    lcoePlantTotal.save = "D:\\02_ArcGIS\\Python" + str(lcoePlantTotal) + ".img"

Comment: Here is the message error:
    
    Runtime error 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 44, in <module>
      File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4049, in Times
        in_raster_or_constant2)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper
        result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4046, in wrapper
        return _wrapLocalFunctionRaster(u"Times_sa", ["Times", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
    RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset D:\02_ArcGIS\Python\LCOE_test\DNI does not exist or is not supported

Comment: Please don't try to put code/error messages in the comments section. Edit your question instead, referencing a particular answer if necessary.

Comment: You are correct. Wasn't awared of that rule. Thank you very much.